# Powershell: Redirect echo of user input to multiple text files

Tags: redirect, powershell

First of all, I'm quite new to Powershell and scripting in general your patience is greatly appreciated.

I have a script that writes values inputted by the user (a Fully Qualified Domain Name) to a document called "servers.txt". I would like instead, to append to several copies of "servers.txt" located in different locations. Unfortunately having only one "servers.txt" file isn't an option, the various scripts that access the various "servers.txt" files sometimes require an independent file with unique data, but every few months I have to make them uniform (or at least all containing a certain entry) for a scheduled event.

I checked the get-help for out-file and saw no reference to multiple outputs. I googled around for a while, but it doesn't seem many people want to do what I'm attempting (or I'm doing a crappy job of asking the question).

Here is the Script:

```
# This variable exists to ensure the loop continues forever. 
$yes="y"

#Information for the user
ECHO "This script adds your input to every servers.txt file. You may press "VIEW" at any time to see what currently exists in a servers.txt file"

#Loop. The script requests the FQDN or the command "exit" or "view". Exit ends the script, VIEW shows the current content of servers.txt. If an FQDN is tested for positively, it will append the user's value to servers.txt
do {

$a = read-host "Please Input Server FQDN here, or type EXIT to end the loop"

#test for command to quit (exit)
if  ($a -eq "exit")
    {
        exit

    }
#test for command to view contents of servers.txt
if  ($a -eq "view")
    {
        get-content servers.txt

    }
#if not exit or view, check if this is a proper FQDN
else
        {

        IF ($a -match "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)?\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|internal)$")

#If test for FQDN is positive append value to servers.txt
            {
                echo $a | out-file "servers.txt" -append
            }
#If test fails, return error

        ELSE 
            {echo "Entry is Invalid"}


        }



}

#continue looping forever because YES always is equal to Y

while ($yes -eq "y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Add-Content:

```
"TESTING" | Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\test1.txt","C:\temp\test2.txt"
```